# VBA code to create a date schedule

Tags: vba, excel

I am not very good with VBA and I would be glad if you could help me with the following.

I need to create a code that, given a starting date and a final date (final obervation date) calculates the intermidiate observation dates according to a certain frequency (i.e., quarterly, semi annually..). In this dates I do not want to include weekends.

Moreover, I need also to determine another set of dates which are the payment dates given by the observation dates + 5 business days. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Then we'll be able to help much better.

Comment: if you're not good with VBA then maybe you want to use a formula in cell `A2` `=if(A1<>"",if(A1+$C$1<$B$1,A1+$C$1,""),"")`  Put your start date in `A1` end date in `B1` and interval in days in `C1` then auto-fill the formula down to get all the dates.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I guess that sounds harsher than i meant it.

Comment: The comment by @Gordon gives you an easy way to get the "observation dates".  The "payment dates" would then be easily calculated as `=WORKDAY(A1,5)`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Because I was an unintentional jerk, I decided to help you along the way. I am not doing everything for you, but this is my apology to you.

```
Private Sub datesched()
    Dim UserInput As Variant
    UserInput = CDate(InputBox("give me a date"))

    Dim QuartelyDate As Date
    For i = 1 To 4
        QuarterlyDate = DateAdd("m", 4, UserInput)
        Debug.Print ; QuarterlyDate
    Next i

    Dim SemiAnnual As Date
    For i = 1 To 2
        SemiAnnual = DateAdd("m", 6, UserInput)
        Debug.Print ; SemiAnnual
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A little bit more of help or comments to give me an idea about the code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Btw, could you also tell me how can I add a specific calendar in excel with specific non trading days? I have already all the dates I need and I want excel to understand that there are other days a part from weekends which have to be considered as non business days..